# Users having read access for an Opportunity is not be able to attach a file in that Opportunity

Tags: profile, permissions, attachment

Users having read access for an Opportunity are not be able to attach a file in that Opportunity. Kindly help me to accomplish this.

Comment: check the permission.

Comment: Can they attach attachments to other objects ? They may need edit perms. Have you already done some actions to solve this yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

The users permission for notes and attachments are inherited from the parent record and the user who is trying to add/edit an attachment is required to have edit access on the Parent record, either via ownership or via sharing settings.

> To delete a note or attachment, you must be the owner of the note or
>   attachment or an administrator with the "Modify all Data" permission. 
>   Note ownership is determined by the owner field. Attachment ownership
>   is determined by the created by field.

Answer (score -1):

In order to attach a file, you should have “edit” permission on the object. So, read access for an Opportunity is not sufficient to allow attaching a file.

Also, if you are trying to attach documents of extensions .htm, .html, .htt, .htx, .mhtm, .mhtml, .shtm, .shtml, .acgi, .svg “Don't allow HTML uploads as attachments or document records” should be unchecked. This setting is available in Setup – Security Controls - File Upload and Download Security.

The following Salesforce help links can be referred for more details about attaching files in Salesforce and to configure File Upload and Download Security Settings.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_add.htm
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193434&language=en_US